# Rescale matrix by summating over pixels

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, resize

Is there a quick way to rescale a matrix by simply adding adjacent pixels?

So for a `X=N*M` matrix you get a `Y=(N/n) *(N/m)` where `n * m` is the area I should add the pixel in.

I've been doing that manually (via script) but I think there has to be somewhere a way to do it.

```
for i in range(0, X.shape[0]/n):
    for j in range(0, X.shape[1]/m):
        Y[i, j] = np.sum(X[i*n:i*n+n, j*m:j*m+m])
```

E.G.

```
X = [[0 1 2 3]
     [2 3 4 5]
     [3 4 6 8]
     [2 3 4 5]]

Y = [[ 6 14]
     [12 23]]
```

Comment: Just used a convolution with [[1,1], [1,1]] kernel and pass of 2 pixel

Answer (score 2):

A pure numpy way would be to reshape the matrix into more axes and sum over the appropiate axes.

```
Y = X.reshape(X.shape[0]/n, n, X.shape[1]/m, m).sum((1, 3))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can vectorize your code by using the functions [`skimage.utils.view_as_blocks`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.view_as_blocks) and [`numpy.sum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html#numpy.sum):

```
import numpy as np
from skimage.util import view_as_blocks

N, M = 4, 4
n, m = 2, 2

X = np.random.randint(size=(N, M), low=0, high=10)
blocks = view_as_blocks(X, (N//n, M//n))
Y = np.sum(blocks, axis=(-1, -2))
```

`N`and `M` have to be integer multiples of `n` and `m`, respectively. Otherwise you'll get the following error:

> ValueError: `block_shape` is not compatible with `arr_in`

**Sample run**

```
In [74]: X
Out[74]: 
array([[5, 6, 3, 7],
       [5, 0, 3, 0],
       [6, 1, 8, 0],
       [4, 0, 7, 2]])

In [75]: Y
Out[75]: 
array([[16, 13],
       [11, 17]])
```